(@syncfusion/ej2-ng-charts) which declares ChartModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy
Getting below error when im using angular15 and install @syncfusion/ej2-ng-charts
any help is much appreciated.
Error = This likely means that the library (@syncfusion/ej2-ng-charts) which declares ChartModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
I tried to install @syncfusion/ej2-ng-charts in angular15 and in my project i alredy used angular2-chartjs but i want to remove angular2-chartjs and use @syncfusion/ej2-ng-charts but im getting so many errors
